# Creating a Python Dictionary using Keys with Wildcards

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, wildcard

I am looking to create **a Python dictionary with keys that contain wildcards**. Is this possible?

Currently, I am creating a program that finds the point values associated with a particular type of scoring. For example, what is the point value associated with a `'Four-of-a-Kind'` or a `'Straight'`. The problem is that there are several types of four of a kind (i.e. `'Four-of-a-Kind-(1)', 'Four-of-a-Kind-(2)',...`) that all have the same point values.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
mode_value = {'1-Spot': 100,
              '5-Spot': 500,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(1)': 300,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(2)': 200,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(3)': 300,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(4)': 400,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(5)': 500,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(6)': 600,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(1)': 1000,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(2)': 1000,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(3)': 1000,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(4)': 1000,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(5)': 1000,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(6)': 1000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(1)': 2000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(2)': 2000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(3)': 2000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(4)': 2000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(5)': 2000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(6)': 2000,
                 ...
              'Straight': 1500 }
```

Given the dictionary has a key containing the scoring mode, it returns the value of that particular mode:

```
In [1]: mode_value['Four-of-a-Kind-(3)']
Out [1]: 1000
```

This creates a large amount of repetition. For example, when I get to the `'Four-of-a-Kind-w/Pair-(*)'` which can be with any of the six types of four of a kinds with any of the six types of two of a kinds, all producing the same score.

**Here is something like what I want:**

```
mode_value = {'1-Spot': 100,
              '5-Spot': 500,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(1)': 300,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(2)': 200,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(3)': 300,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(4)': 400,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(5)': 500,
              'Three-of-a-Kind-(6)': 600,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-(*)': 1000,
              'Five-of-a-Kind-(*)': 2000,
              'Six-of-a-Kind-(*)': 3000,
              'Three-Pairs-(*)': 1500,
              'Two-Triplets-(*)': 2500,
              'Four-of-a-Kind-w/Pair-(*)': 1500,
              'Straight': 1500 }
```

**What I have seen so far:**

A search of the forms only pulls up questions about using a wildcard in querying a dictionary, not creating one. (i.e. [Python, accessing dictionary with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024822/python-accessing-dictionary-with-wildcards))

Another question used comprehension to create a similar effect (i.e. [Creating a Python dictionary using a comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413048/creating-a-python-dictionary-using-a-comprehension)), but I feel like given how most things are in Python, there has to be a simpler way.

Again, is this possible in Python? It would greatly simplify writing similar bits of this part of the code for other types of scoring.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you just want to know if this is possible, or do you want to reduce your memory or processing complexity?

Comment: A way to create this dictionary without typing out all the permutations. Because it would 1) take forever, and 2) not be easy to change if I add, remove, or modify the scoring modes it contains.

Comment: What's generating the strings you're using as keys? Where are those coming from?

Comment: A function that analyzes the available hand and identifies all the possible scoring modes.

Comment: You should store your data differently. I'd start by modifying the output of that function. This is not what dictionaries are for.

Comment: @MichaelMolter, I think you solved this yourself. You are wanting a **function** that analyzes a hand. Just create a function that takes in the type of hand, and the number of cards (optional) and return the corresponding number. Each type can perform the necessary math to create the respective score value. If you *really* want to turn this into a `dict`, then set up a loop with all possible combinations, and call that function repeatedly to store each possible value into a `dict` with a `tuple` as its key. I can elaborate as an answer as necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionary with wildcard key matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952323/iterating-over-dictionary-with-wildcard-key-matching)

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952323/iterating-over-dictionary-with-wildcard-key-matching question is the inverse of what I am asking. I am not searching for a key with wildcards, I am generating a dictionary with wildcards. The callee will always provide a literal search key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible function you can use is the following based on the inputs you have provided:

```
def hand_score(hand, cards=None):
    fixed = {
        "Four-of-a-Kind": 1000,
        "Four-of-a-Kind-w/Pair": 1500,
        "Five-of-a-Kind": 2000,
        "Six-of-a-Kind": 3000,
        "Three-Pairs": 1500,
        "Two-Triplets": 2500,
        "Straight": 1500
        }
    if hand in fixed:
        return fixed[hand]
    if hand == "Three-of-a-Kind":
        return 100 * cards
    if hand.endswith("-Spot"):
        return 100 * int(hand[0])
    return 0
```

Where `fixed` would be all types of hands that have a fixed score.

Comment: I plan to implement a similar idea to this comment. I now believe that there is not built-in 'wild-card' dictionary key, but when such a feature is necessary, I will use a method like yours that simulates a dictionary with some additional logic. In this case, the dictionary is very small, so performance isn't a huge issue, but I could see that being a major limitation for this approach when the dictionaries are larger.

Comment: Well, if you really wanted a dictionary, you can use a function like this to generate one given that you go through every possible scenario and save that somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should have the values separately (and without the parenthesis):

```
type = 'Three-of-a-Kind'
mode = '1'
```

(This can either be done by parsing or storing the data differently.)

After that, you can look at the problem a little differently.

You are looking to get the value from a key that matches either `type-(mode)` or `type-(*)`. The solution is to simply use a regex while matching, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29952674/6083675).

The code in your case could be:

```
for key in dict:
    if re.match(type + r'-\((' + mode + r'|\*)\)', key):
        print(dict[key])
```

This will match your current key format.

It simplifies the regex to change the format to `Four-of-a-Kind1` (where `Four-of-a-Kind*` is the wildcard version):

```
for key in dict:
    if re.match(type + r'(' + mode + r'|\*)', key):
        print(dict[key])
```

Comment: This answer is syntactically invalid and makes little sense. First you say to split up the way things are stored to get away from the `type-(whatever)` construction, then you give a poorly explained example of how to parse the very thing you just said not to do.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You're right that I forgot the `r`, but you have misunderstood the rest of what my code does. I have not explained how to parse the string (as it is very easy to do). Instead, this is how one would retrieve the key from the dictionary. I do accept the point about the format, but I was only following the OP's key style. I have given an alternative format and regex that is more readable.

Comment: I guess you're right that I don't understand. I'll let someone who does cancel my upvote. My point about your syntax was not the lack of raw string literals but the lack of a colon after your (now both) for statements.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That part of the code was copied directly from the linked source (which I will edit too). I'm not terribly familiar with Python, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: I like that this answer is true to the request, but leveraging the `re` module seems a little overkill. Nonetheless, thank you for your contribution.